# Require() file stopped working after update to php56

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

After updating to PHP version 5.6.23, `require()` stopped working for files that are rewritten in `.htaccess`. The page works fine when requiring the actual file `Qb0XTST.php`.

I did try updating composer.

Error message:

> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'staffHelp' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php56/pear') in /home/mittensl/public_html/Staff-Lounge.php on line 3

Rewrite engine works for every other file (I haven't discovered any errors yet):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^staffHelp/?$    Qb0XTST.php    [NC,L]
```

Comment: There are two options, either that file does not exist or PHP does not have required permissions to open it.

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk How can I check, if php does have required permissions?

Comment: @TomaszKowalczyk Alright, I found out that the file has chmod (I assume) 644 permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`require`](http://php.net/require) (and [`include`](http://php.net/include)) has nothing to do with Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). It looks for the *path* given and not for some rewritten URL.

The error message confirms this. `require('staffHelp');` looks for a file `staffHelp`, and does not involve Apache's rewrite rules in any way.

Apache's rewrite rules will be applied only, when there's an HTTP request coming in, which doesn't happen, when PHP `require`s or `include`s a file.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!